# JSON API on Wordpress - creating a post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, wordpress

I try to create a form on my website where a visitor will be able to make a post in a specific category. The problem is that I get a 404 page not found error. Here is my code:

```
echo "<textarea cols='50' rows='10' style='font-size: 24px;'></textarea><br><br>";
echo "<button id='sendmessage' style='padding:10px'>Submit</button>";

echo "<script>
    jQuery('#sendmessage').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.ajax({
        // get the nonce
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: '/api/get_nonce/?controller=posts&method=create_post',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function  (data) {
            // create the post
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: '/api/create_post/',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: {nonce: data.nonce, status:'publish', categories:'mycategory', title:'xxxx', content:'xxxx'},
                success: function  (data) {

                },
                error: function  (data) {
                    console.log('error');
                }
            });
        },
        error: function  (data) {
            console.log('error');
        }
        });
    });
    </script>"
```

On the console, I get this error:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/api/get_nonce/?controller=posts&method=create_post&callback=jQuery111109654319724222027_1423235015042&_=1423235015043"
```

I am working on localhost right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those URL's to work you should enable user-friendly permalinks. Else you should use ?json=get_nonce&controller=posts&method=create_post

Comment: Now I have 200 OK for get and post but the post isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

your code is working fine i changed the status to draft 
data: {nonce: data.nonce, status:'draft', categories:'mycategory', title:'xxxx', content:'xxxx'},

Answer (score 0):

You can use below WP REST API create post method,
Reference URL for create post : https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#create-a-post

Cookie or Nonce based Auth refer below URLs,
http://v2.wp-api.org/guide/authentication/
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/